# How to close the port without crashing/freezing the program?

Tags: vb.net

I have written a Visual Basic program which revives data from a PIC24 MicroControlelr via a serial port and prints the data to a RichTextBox which I later can save to a .txt file.
When I try to close the port half the time it closes fine and I am able to save the text from the RichTextBox, but a lot of the time the program freezes and needs to be restarted. 
The code below is what I use to close the Comm port

```
Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf run_Disconnect)

Private Sub run_Disconnect()
    MyApplication.DoEvents()
    Tester_Comm.Close()
End Sub
```

How do I get is so I am able to close the Comm port without it freezing so often?

Comment: That's how I close my COM ports (I don't use `.DoEvents()` though).  It's never caused a problem.  You might want to check that you are stopping all the routines/threads that are using the port BEFORE you attempt to close it!
Also, add more error checking (`Try/Catch/Finally`) to your code...

Comment: The problem is located in your DataReceived event handler.  Don't make blocking calls, like Invoke(), use BeginInvoke() instead.

Comment: Are you using the SerialPort component in VB.NET toolbox? That's what I use for serial reading. And if you use that, you don't need to start a new thread for closing the port